# How do I solve this logarithm problem?

Tags: logarithms

I'm trying to solve this problem:

> If $\log_{27}(a)=b$, find $\log_{\sqrt[6]{a}}\sqrt{3}$

However, I'm unable to see any connection in those given information. How can I solve this logarithm?

Comment: `I'm unable to see any connection in those given information` What do you know about logarithms change of base?

Comment: @dxiv you mean this notation: $log_ab=\frac{1}{log_ba}$?

Comment: @Steve: That's not notation, that's a formula - that seems relevant in this case - but I would just use $\log_a b=\frac{\log b}{\log a}$ (from which your formula follows).

Comment: @Steve And more generally ${\log _{a}b={\frac {\log _{c}b}{\log _{c}a}}.\,}$

Comment: ok, I used the formula as follows: $\frac{log3}{log\sqrt[6]{a}}$, since $log\sqrt[6]{a}=\frac{loga}{6}$, I have this left: $\frac{6log3}{loga}$. What now?

Comment: Why don't you just solve for $a$ and substitute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $\log_{27}(a) = b$ then $a = 27^b$. Then:
$$\sqrt[6]{a} = (27^b)^\frac{1}{6}  = (3^{3 \cdot \frac{1}{6}})^b = 3^\frac{b}{2}$$
$$\log_{\sqrt[6]{a}}x = \log_{3^\frac{b}{2}}x = \frac{\log_{3}x}{\log_{3}3^\frac{b}{2}} = \frac{2}{b}\log_{3}x$$
Since $x = \sqrt{3}$ then
$$\frac{2}{b}\log_{3}x = \frac{2}{b}\cdot\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{b}$$